# Set timeout for Cloud Functions for Firebase does not persist in the Console; is this a bug?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

***Update: I updated the question, to reflect what I described in the body of the question, and what was happening at the time. It also justifies why I did not mark Sanyam's response as correct. There was a bug in the Console that was causing the timeout values to be ephemeral. @MichaelBleigh's response was the most pertinent, letting me know when the issue was resolved.***

I have a Cloud Function that needs to run past the default 60 second timeout in some edge-cases.

The issue is, while this value can be changed in the Cloud Functions section of the Google Cloud Developer Console, it reverts to the original default after each deploy.

Is there a way I can persist the changes to this setting, perhaps in one of the Firebase configuration files?

Comment: You can edit the timeout by going to the Google Cloud console for the project and going to the Cloud Functions dashboard there. **However**, there is currently a known issue where the timeout will be reset on every deploy. We are looking into fixing this in the near future.

Comment: Yes, I am noticing that this value is reset to the original default after each deploy.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh +1 for a fix here. This makes long running cloud functions extremely difficult to manage.

Comment: There was a fix released for this in a recent Firebase CLI version! Redeploy should preserve timeout and memory settings that you made in the cloud console now.

Comment: Awesome!!! ... Just redeployed using the latest Firebase CLI and my Google Cloud Functions preferences persisted from the previous version :)

Comment: @MichaelBleigh - this works now, but now I can't seem to save the "retry on failure" flag and I wonder if it is related.  I hit Edit, click the box, then save - others fields update, but the "retry on failure" box always goes back to unchecked.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh is there a way to set this via firebase.json? Also how can the increase be done when running locally using `firebase serve --only functions`?

Comment: @gligoran - Hopefully Michael can weigh in, but there isn't a way to set timeout in the firebase.json. Firebase.json docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config

Answer (score 56):

Default timeout can be changed here https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list
`select function` >`test function` > `edit` > `timeout`

Comment: one can also now set the timeout and memory configuration per function declaration right in the code. Check my answer below for more details

Answer (score 55):

Starting [functions v2.0.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v2.0.0) you can also set the timeout in your function declaration as described in the doc under the ["Set timeout and memory allocation"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) section:

```
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '1GB'
}

exports.myStorageFunction = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  .storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize((object) = > {
    // do some complicated things that take a lot of memory and time
  });
```

As release notes also highlighted:

> You will need firebase-tools >=v4.0.0.

And on Mac you can get the latest `firebase-tools` with the following command:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Also note the limitations and valid values as per the doc link above:

```
The maximum value for timeoutSeconds is 540, or 9 minutes. 
Valid values for memory are:

128MB
256MB
512MB
1GB
2GB
4GB
8GB
```

Comment: There is a max limit of 9 minutes( 540 seconds)

Comment: thanks @krishnazden, added that part of the doc for shortcut

Answer (score 4):

After you select your function and then press "Edit" it is located under the "More" drop-down at the bottom of the page. The current max is 540 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Per @MichaelBleigh's comment. This has been resolved in the latest version of the Firebase CLI (3.7.0 at the time of this post).

If you are still experiencing this issue, make sure you are using the latest version of the Firebase CLI.

Comment: How was it resolved? Is there a higher default? A way to specify a per function timeout value in the firebase.json? I checked the CLI reference and didn’t see anything.

Comment: This gets set in the Cloud Functions section of the Google Cloud Developer Console. 1 Navigate to your project: https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?project=<your-project-id>. 2. Click "Edit" to adjust Timeout.

Comment: We still got the issue here, need to specify the timeout after each deploy

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to set timeout for HTTP cloud function you can do so for V2 generation like this:

```
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 10,
};

export const httpGoogleGeminyWrapper = onRequest(runtimeOpts, async (req, res) => {

});
```

More in official documentation [Call functions via HTTP requests

][1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd)