# Firebase: Using an asyncronous call as part of a HTTP trigger without timing out?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am currently learning firebase and I am trying to trigger an asynchronous Api call as part of a http trigger.

In the docs [it says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> Resolve functions that perform asynchronous processing by returning a JavaScript promise.
>
> Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().
>
> Terminate a synchronous function with a return; statement.

So what method could I use to make the network call without falling foul of the 60s limit - can I extend this?

Currently just calling to the network will occasionally time out as it goes over the 60s limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTTPS trigger is *always* timing out, that means you aren't fully following the advice of the documentation you cited and always returning a response to the client.

If your HTTPS trigger simply takes over a minute to complete, and you need more time, you can [increase the timeout in the Cloud console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353687/where-can-i-set-the-default-timeout-for-cloud-functions-for-firebase).

Comment: Thanks Doug - I managed to get it working.  I didn't fully understand how to use promises - but the Youtube Firecasts that your team produced really helped a lot.  Required watching in my opinion.  Thanks for the great help.  I understand a lot more now..