# Firebase high volume of queries: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

In reference to this answer [large number of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964407/9367155) of how to handle a high number of queries I have regrouped the queries as shown using the 'lodash' library which works for a low number of queries however firebase returns an error

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Which I  know means that the arrays have grown too large however, when I try running pure Javascript Promises with a 10 ms timer the code seems to hold up to 1,000,000 as shown in that answer. I am not sure if this is a firebase or a node.js issue but given that firebase real time database can store millions of records in a JSON tree there must be a better way to process so many promises. I have largely based the approach off of these three questions, this was the original problem [Find element nodes contained in another node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952903/how-do-i-efficiently-find-if-one-set-of-nodes-has-elements-contained-in-another) , this approach for checking the database which requires so many reads [check if data exists in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24826338/9367155), and this approach for speeding up the requests [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)

I am not sure if I am performing all of these reads correctly especially since it is such a high volume, thank you.

```
exports.postMadeByFriend = functions.https.onCall(async (data,context) => {
    const mainUserID = "hJwyTHpoxuMmcJvyR6ULbiVkqzH3";
    const follwerID = "Rr3ePJc41CTytOB18puGl4LRN1R2"
    const otherUserID = "q2f7RFwZFoMRjsvxx8k5ryNY3Pk2"

    var promises = [];
    console.log("start")

    var refs = [];

    for(var x = 0; x < 100000; x +=1){

        if (x === 999){
            const ref = admin.database().ref(`Followers`).child(mainUserID).child(follwerID)
            refs.push(ref);
            continue;
        } 
        const ref =  admin.database().ref(`Followers`).child(mainUserID).child(otherUserID);
        refs.push(ref);
    }

    function runQuery(ref){
        return ref.once('value');
    }

    const batches = _.chunk(refs, 10000);
    refs = [];
    const results = [];
    while (batches.length) {
      const batch = batches.shift();
      const result = await Promise.all(batch.map(runQuery));
      results.push(result)
    }
     _.flatten(results);

     console.log("results: " + JSON.stringify(results));

})
```

Comment: Your indentation appeared to be wrong for the last half of your code.  Please check that it's correct now.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for fixing it, I apologize. Also a very big thank you for your youtube video series on Promises they were a great help, well delivered and did an excellent job in explaining all about asynchronous operations in node.js.