# Firestore cloud function to recursively update subcollection/collectionGroup

Tags: javascript, firebase, recursion, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this cloud function:

```
import pLimit from "p-limit";


const syncNotificationsAvatar = async (
  userId: string,
  change: Change<DocumentSnapshot>
) => {
  if (!change.before.get("published") || !change.after.exists) {
    return;
  }

  const before: Profile = change.before.data() as any;
  const after: Profile = change.after.data() as any;
  const keysToCompare: (keyof Profile)[] = ["avatar"];
  if (
    arraysEqual(
      keysToCompare.map((k) => before[k]),
      keysToCompare.map((k) => after[k])
    )
  ) {
    return;
  }

  const limit = pLimit(1000);

  const input = [
    limit(async () => {
      const notifications = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collectionGroup("notifications")
        .where("userId", "==", userId)
        .limit(1000)
        .get()

      await Promise.all(
        chunk(notifications.docs, 500).map(
          async (docs: admin.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot[]) => {
            const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
            for (const doc of docs) {
              batch.update(doc.ref, {
                avatar: after.avatar
              });
            }
            await batch.commit();
          }
        )
      );
    })
  ];

  return await Promise.all(input);
};
```

How can I recursively update the `notifications` collection but first limit the query to `1.000` documents (until there are not more documents) and then `batch.update` them? I'm afraid this query will timeout since collection could grow big over time.

Comment: You're using `p-limit` but you actually pass just 1 promise to the `input` array using the `limit` function; you don't need `p-limit` because you don't care how many promises will be run concurrently. You don't have to limit the fetched documents to 1000 (*and thus do any kind of fetch recursions*) because you can increase the timeout and memory usage of your function, see [Set timeout for Cloud Functions for Firebase does not persist in the Console; is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353687/set-timeout-for-cloud-functions-for-firebase-does-not-persist-in-the-console-is).

Comment: You can use [Query Cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to fetch chunks of documents but I don't recommend to do that. Be careful on how often the system will call that function though because it will have `run times X documents` reads/writes charges.

Comment: Thanks Christos, i'm the guy who had pr'ed the everypay repo some time ago!

Comment: Wow Stathis! Yes I remember you, you saved that package from *lint-less* and *pretty-less*, good job there . Regarding the problem here, I think you should refactor the code a little bit and try to ditch `p-limit`. Remember that each `batch.commit()` is actually **one** promise and not every `batch.update`, so if you have 5000 documents there will be actually 10 batch commits/promises with the 500 batch limit. You can try query cursors, but I wouldn't bother doing that inside a cloud function (*maybe I would on client for memory usage issues*) and would go with memory and timeout increment.

Comment: Hey @ChristosLytras, found a solution, ditched pLimit and created a recursive function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting a solution I worked out, not following the context of the question though but it can easily be combined. Hope it helps someone else.

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

const onResults = async (
  query: admin.firestore.Query,
  action: (batch: number, docs: admin.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot[]) => Promise<void>
) => {
  let batch = 0;
  const recursion = async (start?: admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => {
    const { docs, empty } = await (start == null
      ? query.get()
      : query.startAfter(start).get());
    if (empty) {
      return;
    }
    batch++;
    await action(
      batch,
      docs.filter((d) => d.exists)
    ).catch((e) => console.error(e));
    await recursion(docs[docs.length - 1]);
  };
  await recursion();
};

const getMessages = async () => {
  const query = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("messages")
    .where("createdAt", ">", new Date("2020-05-04T00:00:00Z"))
    .limit(200);

  const messages: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData[] = [];

  await onResults(query, async (batch, docs) => {
    console.log(`Getting Message: ${batch * 200}`);
    docs.forEach((doc) => {
       messages.push(doc.data());
    });
  });
  return messages;
};
```

Comment: Very interesting usage of query cursors and promises! Did you test its performance running against multiple (*thousands*) documents? Well done! +1

Comment: No not yet, I’ll run it on production and leave a comment about results.

Comment: Hey @ChristosLytras, took  ~13secs on ~10.000 documents

Comment: Why I think it's a lot for updating documents? Are you satisficed with that performance? Where do you have the update document code? Isn't this for updating the users avatars? The recursion is pretty good but I think you should try and combine it with create/commit batches of 500 (*as in your O/P*) along with the recursion to see what results you'll get. Batch updates of 500 docs chunks take less time than updating those in a loop.

Comment: In this recursion case I do not need updating, just reading. I'll try to combine it with update query and let you know the results. Thanks for the additional info.