# Firebase Cloud Function times out after 60000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am trying to use a `Cloud-Function` to export a `Collection` in from `Cloud-Storage`.

I followed [this](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exporting-firestore-collection-csv-into-cloud-storage-on-demand-the-easy-way-4a4a08c664ab) blog and deployed the following function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const firebase = require("firebase-admin");
const { parseAsync } = require('json2csv');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const os = require("os");


const generateHostsCsv = functions.region("europe-west1").pubsub
  .topic("generate-hosts-csv")
  .onPublish(async message => {

    // gets the documents from the firestore collection
    const hostsSnapshot = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("data")
      .doc("analytics")
      .collection("hosts")
      .get();

    const hosts = hostsSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    // csv field headers
    const fields = [
      "hostName",
      "count",
    ];

    // get csv output
    const output = await parseAsync(hosts, { fields });

    // generate filename
    const dateTime = new Date().toISOString().replace(/\W/g, "");
    const filename = `hosts_${dateTime}.csv`;

    const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //write contents of csv into the temp file
      fs.writeFile(tempLocalFile, output, error => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        const bucket = firebase.storage().bucket();

        // upload the file into the current firebase project default bucket
        bucket
           .upload(tempLocalFile, {
            // Workaround: firebase console not generating token for files
            // uploaded via Firebase Admin SDK
            // https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/694
            metadata: {
              metadata: {
                firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuidv4(),
              }
            },
          })
          .then(() => resolve())
          .catch(errorr => reject(errorr));
      });
    });
  });

module.exports = { generateHostsCsv };
```

When I let it run, I only see this in my logs:

> Function execution took 60000 ms, finished with status: 'timeout

But no file was created in my storage. What am I missing here?
Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Three observations: 1) The code was doing very well using async/await, until things went wrong with an unnecessary `new Promise`.  If you want to write a file in node using a promise-based API, how about using the [fs promises API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)?  2) Consider logging the progress of the function after each async step to figure out which part is causing the unexpected delay.

Comment: 3) If this function actually needs more than 60 seconds after all, just [increase the timeout](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation).

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the quick response! Just added logs and tis time it worked perfeclty fine (only took 22.000 seconds). Weird, that the times before it was taken way longer, even though I change nothing? But it's working now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it worked after I tried it for the third time.

Thanks @Doug for the help. I [increased the timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353687/set-timeout-for-cloud-functions-for-firebase-does-not-persist-in-the-console-is) and also added some `logs` so I can see what exactly is causing the issue.